Modifying window size with GLFW
When I use GLFW to create a window with glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE); to remove window decorations, how can I resize the window by dragging with the mouse?
"I tried using glfwSetCursorEnterCallback(window, cursor_enter_callback) but it doesn't seem to work.

See the documentation

When you are setting up GLFW add the following hint:
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);

If you want to resize the window programmatically you can still use:
glfwSetWindowSize(window, width, height);


After using glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE), setting glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE) seems to have no effect.

@xMonody Ah ok this is because on most operating systems clicking the border is what prompts the ability to change window size. I would then say you should take advantage of the mouse left/entered callback and then check if the left mouse button is pressed with glfwGetMouseButton. Then once detected they are dragging the the mouse then resize appropriately. This seems to be the only way around it I can think of but it is very long winded so if you can afford to still use decorated then I would

I understand now. I think I have a rough idea of how to proceed. Thank you very much.
